# Protractor Test with oracle Db

Tags: javascript, database, protractor, cucumber, node-oracledb

I requirement to test the DB alongside my angular app. The scenario is such that I do something on UI and see if the value persists in the DB(Oracle)

For this purpose, I installed node oracle DB package and was able to run a simple SELECT statement using the command "Node filename.js". The config and the select statement were present in the filename.js

Next, I tried to include the same steps in my step definition. The first step of my test case navigates to the application home page and the next step is to run a simple select statement. I have no asserts as I wanted to first get a basic query working

Here is my step def

```
let oracledb = require('oracledb');
let dbConfig = require('../configs/dbConfig');

Given(/^I run a random select query$/, function() {

    let sql2 = "Select * from tablename Where columname  = 8888901";
    oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig).then(function(connection) {
        //return console.log('Connected to database');
        return connection.execute(sql2).then(function(result, err) {
            return console.log(result.rows.toString());
        });
    });

});
```

When the test runs the browser opens and the home page is loaded and then the test is passed. I don't think the 2nd step is even run as the query result is not printed in the console.

Could someone please point me in the right direction. Can protractor work with OracleDB? have I written the test correct? I have so many questions regarding this and there is not a single online sample for a protractor test with oracledb. Any inputs here will be helpful, thanks

Comment: Add `return` keyword before `oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig)` statement to make your test wait till the asynchronous task(sql query) to complete its execution.

Comment: Agree with @sudharsan, You need to return a promise of call `callback` for each cucumber step definition. More detail look the cucumber doc: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md